# Adding form elements dynamically in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a problem with loading form elements ajaxically.

ResourcePipeline.jsp:

```
    <head>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var resourcePosition = 0;
            $('#addResourceButton').click(function() {
                resourcePosition++;
         alert(resourcePosition);
                $.get("appendResourceView.page", { fieldId: resourcePosition},
                    function(data){
                        $('#submitRow').before(data);
                        alert(resourcePosition+ "after sending the url");
                });
            });
        });
    </head>

<body>
 <input type="button" id="addResourceButton" value="+" />
</body>
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/appendResourceView.page")
protected String appendResourceField(@RequestParam Integer fieldId, ModelMap model )
{   
    List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    Resource resource = new Resource();
    resources.add(resource);        
    Demand demand = new Demand();   
    demand.setResources(resources);

    Map map = new HashMap();        

    map.put("demand", demand);      



    model.addAttribute("resourceNumber", fieldId);
    model.addAttribute("map", map);



    return "resourceInsert.view";
}
```

The jsp is a getting through AJAX call

resourceInsert.jsp:

```
<c:set var="resourceForDemand" value="${map.demand}"></c:set>

 <form:input type="text" class="dater"  path="resourceForDemand.resources[${resourceNumber}].need_From_Date" required="true" />
```

When i try fire the AJAX part, I am getting "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'resourceForDemand' available as request attribute" as error. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not verry comfortable with spring but, in others JEE frameworks, when using ajax to get html from the server, you don't return (or write in the response) elements with jsp syntax but directly html. Try to return a string representing the generated html like `return "<input type=\"text\" class"dater" value=\""+resource.getNeed_From_Date()+"\" />";`

Answer (score 0):

Spring is looking for a model object called `resourceForDemand` but can't find one. Is there any reason that you're using the nested map within the `ModelMap`? You may be better to have a minor refactor of your controller method and expose the `Demand` object in the model directly:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/appendResourceView.page")
protected String appendResourceField(@RequestParam Integer fieldId, ModelMap model )
{   
    List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    Resource resource = new Resource();
    resources.add(resource);        
    Demand demand = new Demand();   
    demand.setResources(resources);


    model.addAttribute("resourceNumber", fieldId);
    model.addAttribute("resourceForDemand", demand);



    return "resourceInsert.view";
}
```

Comment: Actually i am sending many lists to view through map. Thats why I used a map over there. Anyway the problem is solved. Autopopulation list was the root cause of my problem and I switched to Lazylist which now is working like a cheese. Thank you very much Will for your help.